# I want to apply different interval timing for the video in a owl-carousel in bootstrap having 3 images and a video with current interval of 5sec

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, owl-carousel

$(".header-carousel").owlCarousel({
autoplay: true,
smartSpeed: 1500,
loop: true,
nav: false,
dots: true,
animateOut: 'fadeOut',
animateIn: 'fadeIn',
items: 1,
dotsData: true,
});

this is the js code for carousel

$(".header-carousel").owlCarousel({
autoplay: true,
autoplayTimeout: 1000;
smartSpeed: 1500,
loop: true,
nav: false,
dots: true,
animateOut: 'fadeOut',
animateIn: 'fadeIn',
items: 1,
dotsData: true,
});

this applies 10 sec time interval to all the slides and i want it for only the video